# My NIGINX server is down. How do I restart it? I am fairly new to NGINX and CentOS

Tags: nginx, centos

Here is my NGINX configuration file:

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        location / {
            root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

When I type `service nginx start` in my terminal, it shows:

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start nginx.service
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

When I execute `systemctl status nginx.service` it shows:

```
systemctl status nginx.service
nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2016-06-29 10:17:58 EDT; 10s ago
Process: 21459 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 21457 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 14307 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 29 10:17:58 lotto systemd[1]: Starting The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server...
Jun 29 10:17:58 lotto nginx[21459]: nginx: [emerg] unexpected end of file, expecting "}" in /etc/ng...f:80
Jun 29 10:17:58 lotto nginx[21459]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Jun 29 10:17:58 lotto systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 29 10:17:58 lotto systemd[1]: Failed to start The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
Jun 29 10:17:58 lotto systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
Jun 29 10:17:58 lotto systemd[1]: nginx.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

`i install nginx in my remote server`

 but i done some error in my nginx.conf file and could not able to revert back
so it tried to remove my nginx and reconfigure it 
so i used these step which is given in the link to delete my nginx
http://www.ehowstuff.com/how-to-remove-uninstall-nginx-on-centos-7-rhel-7-oracle-linux-7/ 
`then i use
yum remove nginx and again reinstall it`

but when i try 
`sudo systemctl start nginx or [root@lotto nginx]# service nginx start`
 
its showing

Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exitenter code hereed with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
`when i am using 
[root@lotto nginx]# systemctl status nginx.service 
showing`

nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-07-01 07:48:44 EDT; 18s ago Process: 30832 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 30830 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 14307 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 01 07:48:44 lotto systemd[1]: Starting The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server... Jul 01 07:48:44 lotto nginx[30832]: nginx: [emerg] getpwnam("nginx") failed in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:5
Jul 01 07:48:44 lotto nginx[30832]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Jul 01 07:48:44 lotto systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 01 07:48:44 lotto systemd[1]: Failed to start The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
Jul 01 07:48:44 lotto systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state. Jul 01 07:48:44 lotto systemd[1]: nginx.service failed.
and [root@lotto nginx]# journalctl -xe

nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server 
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-07-01 07:48:44 EDT; 18s ago
Process: 30832 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 30830 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 14307 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Comment: You have an error in your nginx.conf file. Can we get a properly formatted view of that?

Comment: worker_processes  2;
 error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
 pid     /var/run/nginx.pid;
 events {
     worker_connections  1024;
 }
http {
         include    /etc/nginx/mime.types;
         default_type  application/octet-stream;
         log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                           '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
         access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

Comment: sendfile        on;
         keepalive_timeout  65;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        server 
        {
            listen  80;
            server_name _;
            location / {
                {
                    root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
                    index  index.html index.htm;
                }
                error_page  500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
                location = /50x.html 
                {
                    root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
                }
            }
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

The error was in your configuration file. I accidentally corrected it when I edited your post because I thought you copied it incorrectly.

This line `Jun 29 10:17:58 lotto nginx[21459]: nginx: [emerg] unexpected end of file, expecting "}" in /etc/ng...f:80` is telling you exactly what when wrong. If the syntax isn't correct, the service won't start.

Add a `}` to the end of your `nginx.conf` file and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

When you have trouble starting nginx service re-check the conf file.
You can check the configuration errors using this

```
nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```